# Show this function is increasing and find its limit at 0.

Tags: analysis, limits-without-lhopital, monotone-functions

Let $0 \leq l < s < u $.  I want to show 2 things:

1) The function $x \mapsto \frac{u^x-s^x}{u^x-l^x}$ defined for $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus{0}$ is increasing.

2) $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{u^x-s^x}{u^x-l^x} = \frac{\ln(u)-\ln(s)}{\ln(u)-\ln(l)}$.

Both these things can be verified on https://www.desmos.com/calculator/trhaqobquo.

Comment: NB/ This may help: For $x >0$ consider the functions $a \mapsto a^x$ for $a \geq 0$.  And for $x<0$ consider the functions $a \mapsto -(a^x)$ for $a \geq 0$.  And notice  informally that the larger x is, the "more convex" the function we are considering is and the larger the ratio $\frac{u^x-s^x}{u^x-l^x}$ becomes.

And for $x=0$, we should consider $a \mapsto \ln(a)$, in which case we get the limit.

Or this is gibberish and may not help and 1) and 2) can be proved more directly.

Comment: Is L'Hospital allowed?

Comment: For #2, rewrite the limit as $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(s/u)^x-1}{x}\cdot \frac{x}{(l/u)^x-1}.$$ Why does the answer immediately follow from that?

Comment: Thanks @FedeX333X

Comment: I think both parts of the question are handled a bit more easily by writing the ratio as $\frac {e^{cx}-e^{bx}} {e^{cx}-e^{ax}}$ where $a=\ln l,b=\ln s,c=\ln u$.

Answer (score 1):

$1)$ Mainly in such situations we count first derivative and here we do it, too (although intuitively we see that this function must be increasing)

$$f'(x)=\left(\dfrac{u^x-s^x}{u^x-l^x}\right)'=\dfrac{(u^x\ln{u}-s^x\ln{s})(u^x-l^x)-(u^x-s^x)(u^x\ln{u}-l^x\ln{l})}{(u^x-l^x)^2}=\dfrac{(u^x)^2 \ln{u}-l^xu^x\ln{u}-s^xu^x\ln{s}+s^xl^x\ln{s}-\left((u^x)^2\ln{u}-u^xl^x\ln{l}-s^xu^x\ln{u}+s^xl^x\ln{l}\right)}{(u^x-l^x)^2}=\dfrac{l^x u^x(\ln{l}-\ln{u})+s^x u^x(\ln{u}-\ln{s})+s^xl^x(\ln{s}-\ln{l})}{(u^x-l^x)^2}=\dfrac{(ul)^x\ln{\frac{l}{u}}+(su)^x\ln{\frac{u}{s}}+(sl)^x\ln{\frac{s}{l}}}{(u^x-l^x)^2}.$$
We can observe that always $f'(x)>0$, because of the assumptions.

$2)$ L'Hospital's rule will be helpful, beacuse this is limit of a type $\left[\frac{0}{0}\right]$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{u^x-s^x}{u^x-l^x}\stackrel{H}{=}\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{u^x\ln{u}-s^x\ln{s}}{u^x\ln{u}-l^x\ln{l}}=\dfrac{\ln{u}-\ln{s}}{\ln{u}-\ln{l}}$$

Comment: It is not that obvious to me why $(ul)^x\ln{\frac{l}{u}}+(su)^x\ln{\frac{u}{s}}+(sl)^x\ln{\frac{s}{l}}$ is positive.